# Swap values of two QML properties

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to swap values of two color properties when user clicks on a button with this QML code:

```
Item {
    property color primaryColor: "black"
    property color secondaryColor: "white"

    MouseArea {
        onClicked: {
            var tmp = primaryColor
            primaryColor = secondaryColor
            secondaryColor = tmp
        }
    }
}
```

But instead of swapping them it just sets both values to `#ffffff`. Adding debug output shows this picture:

```
Code:
        onClicked: {
            var tmp = primaryColor
            console.log(primaryColor, secondaryColor, tmp)
            primaryColor = secondaryColor
            console.log(primaryColor, secondaryColor, tmp)
            secondaryColor = tmp
            console.log(primaryColor, secondaryColor, tmp)
        }

Output:
qml: #000000 #ffffff #000000
qml: #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff
qml: #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff
```

Obiously, it considers `tmp` to be an alias for the `primaryColor` property instead of just a variable with the current value of `primaryColor`.

Changing `var tmp = primaryColor` to `var tmp = primaryColor + ""` fixes the issue but looks ugly. An it's different ugly for each type. **Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same behavior?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.
The first one, mentioned in the comments, is converting properties to strings using `propertyname.toString()`:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent

    onClicked: {
        var tmp = primaryColor.toString()
        console.log(primaryColor, secondaryColor, tmp)
        primaryColor = secondaryColor.toString()
        console.log(primaryColor, secondaryColor, tmp)
        secondaryColor = tmp //no need for toString() here, it is already a string
        console.log(primaryColor, secondaryColor, tmp)
    }
}
```

The second way is creating a `property color tmp` inside the `MouseArea` and use it to swap the values without converting properties to strings:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    property color tmp

    onClicked: {
        tmp = primaryColor
        console.log(primaryColor, secondaryColor, tmp)
        primaryColor = secondaryColor
        console.log(primaryColor, secondaryColor, tmp)
        secondaryColor = tmp
        console.log(primaryColor, secondaryColor, tmp)
    }
}
```

In both cases the result is:

```
qml: #000000 #ffffff #000000
qml: #ffffff #ffffff #000000
qml: #ffffff #000000 #000000
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to achieve the same behavior.

```
onClicked: {
    [ primaryColor, secondaryColor ] = [ secondaryColor.toString(), primaryColor.toString() ]
}
```

This is called destructuring assignment.

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.